# Making an Obstacle System for an Endless Runner Game in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a clone of [google chrome dinosaur game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Game) in Python `pygame`. I don't have much experience with `pygame`. I managed to create all of the dinosaur sprite animations (walking, jumping and bending) and now I'm trying to add the obstacles. So what I want to do is when the user's score surpasses 35, obstacles will start being randomly generated. The problem is that when the score surpasses 35, obstacles appear on top of each other, some appear and disappear constantly and it just looks bad and very laggy. How can I render the obstacles more smoothly? The relevant parts of the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import os
from threading import Thread
pygame.init()

w, h = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
imgX = w
def generate_obstacles():
    global imgX
    obstacles_tuple = (obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3, obstacle4, obstacle5)
    chosen_obstacle = random.choice(obstacles_tuple)
    try:
        if WINDOW.get_width() >= imgX > 0:
            WINDOW.blit(chosen_obstacle, (imgX, 323))
        else:
            imgX = w
    except pygame.error:
        quit()

    pygame.display.update()


def draw():
    WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
    pygame.display.update()


r1, r2 = 5000, 7000
def timer(score):
    global r1, r2
    timer_running = True
    while timer_running:
        rand_time = random.randint(r1, r2)
        pygame.time.delay(rand_time)
        generate_obstacles()

        if r1 >= 500 and r2 >= 500:
            if score % 100 == 0:
                r1 -= 20
                r2 -= 20
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            break



game_intro(True)
run = True
my_sprite = Dino()
speed = 5
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    bgX -= speed
    bgX2 -= speed
    imgX -= speed
    if bgX < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX = floor.get_width()
    if bgX2 < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX2 = floor.get_width()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            with open("highscore.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write(str(my_sprite.high_score))
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            my_sprite.fall()

        if (keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]) and not my_sprite.is_jumping:
            my_sprite.jump()

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            my_sprite.bend()

    draw()
    my_sprite.walk()

    if my_sprite.score >= 35:
        Thread(target=lambda: timer(my_sprite.score)).start()
```

I also made a [video](https://youtu.be/kYV-cAqCPJY) so you can get a better understanding of what the problem is.

Full code:

```
import pygame
import random
import os
from threading import Thread
pygame.init()

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dinosaur Game")
walk1_image = pygame.image.load("images/walk1.png")
walk1 = pygame.transform.scale(walk1_image, (64, 64))
bend1_image = pygame.image.load("images/bend1.png")
bend1 = pygame.transform.scale(bend1_image, (64, 64))
bend2_image = pygame.image.load("images/bend2.png")
bend2 = pygame.transform.scale(bend2_image, (64, 64))
walk2_image = pygame.image.load("images/walk2.png")
walk2 = pygame.transform.scale(walk2_image, (64, 64))
die_image = pygame.image.load("images/die.png")
die = pygame.transform.scale(die_image, (64, 64))
jump_image = pygame.image.load("images/jump.png")
jump = pygame.transform.scale(jump_image, (64, 64))

images_list = [walk1, walk2, die, jump, bend1]
floor_image = pygame.image.load("obstacles/floor-0.png").convert()
floor = pygame.transform.scale(floor_image, (500, 100))
bgX = 0
bgX2 = floor.get_width()
in_main = False

obstacle1_image = pygame.image.load("obstacles/obstacle1.png")
obstacle1 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle1_image, (78, 78))
obstacle2_image = pygame.image.load("obstacles/obstacle2.png")
obstacle2 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle2_image, (156, 78))
obstacle3_image = pygame.image.load("obstacles/obstacle3.png")
obstacle3 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle3_image, (64, 64))
obstacle4_image = pygame.image.load("obstacles/obstacle4.png")
obstacle4 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle4_image, (128, 64))
obstacle5_image = pygame.image.load("obstacles/obstacle5.png")
obstacle5 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle5_image, (192, 64))

def game_intro(intro):
    while intro:
        WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        label = my_font.render("Press space to play", True, (105, 105, 105))
        WINDOW.blit(jump, (125, 200))
        WINDOW.blit(label, (125, 300))
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 20)
        label2 = my_font.render("Made by: Roni", True, (0, 0, 0))
        WINDOW.blit(label2, (10, 480))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event2 in pygame.event.get():
            keys2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if event2.type == pygame.QUIT or keys2[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if keys2[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if not os.path.isfile("highscore.txt"):
                    f = open("highscore.txt", "w")
                    f.write("0")
                    f.close()
                intro = False
                return


class Dino(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dino, self).__init__()
        self.images = [walk1, walk2]
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 323
        self.is_falling = False
        self.is_jumping = False
        self.is_bend = False
        self.is_down = False
        self.score = 0
        self.high_score = 0

    def walk(self):
        self.update_score()
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX, 300))
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX2, 300))
        self.score += 1

        if self.is_jumping:
            WINDOW.blit(jump, (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.is_bend:
            bend_images = [bend1, bend2]
            keys3 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.images):
                self.index = 0
            bend = bend_images[self.index]
            if keys3[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                WINDOW.blit(bend, (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                self.is_bend = False
                self.walk()
        else:
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.images):
                self.index = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.index]
            WINDOW.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

        pygame.display.update()

    def jump(self):
        self.is_jumping = True
        for i in range(3):
            self.y -= 20
            self.walk()
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")

        self.is_falling = True
        pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, 1000)

    def fall(self):
        if self.is_falling:
            while self.y != 323:
                self.y += 20
                self.walk()
                WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
                self.is_falling = False
                self.is_jumping = False
                pygame.display.update()

    def bend(self):
        self.is_bend = True
        self.walk()

    def update_score(self):
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        zeros = 5 - len(str(self.score))
        str_score = "0" * zeros + str(self.score)
        label = my_font.render(str_score, True, (0, 0, 0))
        WINDOW.blit(label, (410, 0))

        with open("highscore.txt", "r") as f:
            self.high_score = int(f.read())

        if self.high_score <= self.score:
            self.high_score = self.score

        zeros2 = 5 - len(str(self.high_score))
        str_score2 = "0" * zeros2 + str(self.high_score)
        label2 = my_font.render("HI: " + str_score2, True, (0, 0, 0))
        WINDOW.blit(label2, (250, 0))
        pygame.display.update()


w, h = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
imgX = w
def generate_obstacles():
    global imgX
    obstacles_tuple = (obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3, obstacle4, obstacle5)
    chosen_obstacle = random.choice(obstacles_tuple)
    try:
        if WINDOW.get_width() >= imgX > 0:
            WINDOW.blit(chosen_obstacle, (imgX, 323))
        else:
            imgX = w
    except pygame.error:
        quit()

    pygame.display.update()


def draw():
    WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
    pygame.display.update()


r1, r2 = 5000, 7000
def timer(score):
    global r1, r2
    timer_running = True
    while timer_running:
        rand_time = random.randint(r1, r2)
        pygame.time.delay(rand_time)
        generate_obstacles()

        if r1 >= 500 and r2 >= 500:
            if score % 100 == 0:
                r1 -= 20
                r2 -= 20
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            break



game_intro(True)
run = True
my_sprite = Dino()
speed = 5
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    bgX -= speed
    bgX2 -= speed
    imgX -= speed
    if bgX < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX = floor.get_width()
    if bgX2 < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX2 = floor.get_width()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            with open("highscore.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write(str(my_sprite.high_score))
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            my_sprite.fall()

        if (keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]) and not my_sprite.is_jumping:
            my_sprite.jump()

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            my_sprite.bend()

    draw()
    my_sprite.walk()

    if my_sprite.score >= 35:
        Thread(target=lambda: timer(my_sprite.score)).start()
```

The problem was solved thanks to @qouify. You can look at his answer to see what solved the problem. Full updated code:

```
import pygame
import random
import os
from threading import Thread
pygame.init()

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dinosaur Game")
walk1_image = pygame.image.load("Dino/walk1.png")
walk1 = pygame.transform.scale(walk1_image, (64, 64))
bend1_image = pygame.image.load("Dino/bend1.png")
bend1 = pygame.transform.scale(bend1_image, (64, 64))
bend2_image = pygame.image.load("Dino/bend2.png")
bend2 = pygame.transform.scale(bend2_image, (64, 64))
walk2_image = pygame.image.load("Dino/walk2.png")
walk2 = pygame.transform.scale(walk2_image, (64, 64))
die_image = pygame.image.load("Dino/die.png")
die = pygame.transform.scale(die_image, (64, 64))
jump_image = pygame.image.load("Dino/jump.png")
jump = pygame.transform.scale(jump_image, (64, 64))

images_list = [walk1, walk2, die, jump, bend1]
floor_image = pygame.image.load("Others/floor-0.png").convert()
floor = pygame.transform.scale(floor_image, (500, 100))
bgX = 0
bgX2 = floor.get_width()
in_main = False

obstacle1_image = pygame.image.load("Obstacles/obstacle1.png")
obstacle1 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle1_image, (78, 78))
obstacle2_image = pygame.image.load("Obstacles/obstacle2.png")
obstacle2 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle2_image, (156, 78))
obstacle3_image = pygame.image.load("Obstacles/obstacle3.png")
obstacle3 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle3_image, (64, 64))
obstacle4_image = pygame.image.load("Obstacles/obstacle4.png")
obstacle4 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle4_image, (128, 64))
obstacle5_image = pygame.image.load("Obstacles/obstacle5.png")
obstacle5 = pygame.transform.scale(obstacle5_image, (192, 64))

def game_intro(intro):
    while intro:
        WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        label = my_font.render("Press space to play", True, (105, 105, 105))
        WINDOW.blit(jump, (125, 200))
        WINDOW.blit(label, (125, 300))
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 20)
        label2 = my_font.render("Made by: Roni Meirom", True, (0, 0, 0))
        WINDOW.blit(label2, (10, 480))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event2 in pygame.event.get():
            keys2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if event2.type == pygame.QUIT or keys2[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if keys2[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if not os.path.isfile("highscore.txt"):
                    f = open("highscore.txt", "w")
                    f.write("0")
                    f.close()
                intro = False
                return


class Dino(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dino, self).__init__()
        self.images = [walk1, walk2]
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 323
        self.is_falling = False
        self.is_jumping = False
        self.is_bend = False
        self.is_down = False
        self.score = 0
        self.high_score = 0

    def walk(self):
        self.update_score()
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX, 300))
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX2, 300))
        self.score += 1

        if self.is_jumping:
            WINDOW.blit(jump, (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.is_bend:
            bend_images = [bend1, bend2]
            keys3 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.images):
                self.index = 0
            bend = bend_images[self.index]
            if keys3[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                WINDOW.blit(bend, (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                self.is_bend = False
                self.walk()
        else:
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.images):
                self.index = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.index]
            WINDOW.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


    def jump(self):
        self.is_jumping = True
        for i in range(3):
            self.y -= 20
            self.walk()
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")

        self.is_falling = True
        pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, 1000)

    def fall(self):
        if self.is_falling:
            self.y += 20
            if self.y != 323:
                self.y = 323
                self.is_falling = False
                self.is_jumping = False

    def bend(self):
        self.is_bend = True
        self.walk()

    def update_score(self):
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        zeros = 5 - len(str(self.score))
        str_score = "0" * zeros + str(self.score)
        label = my_font.render(str_score, True, (0, 0, 0))
        WINDOW.blit(label, (410, 0))

        with open("highscore.txt", "r") as f:
            self.high_score = int(f.read())

        if self.high_score <= self.score:
            self.high_score = self.score

        zeros2 = 5 - len(str(self.high_score))
        str_score2 = "0" * zeros2 + str(self.high_score)
        label2 = my_font.render("HI: " + str_score2, True, (0, 0, 0))
        WINDOW.blit(label2, (250, 0))


w, h = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
imgX = w
def generate_obstacles():
    global imgX
    obstacles_tuple = (obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3, obstacle4, obstacle5)
    chosen_obstacle = random.choice(obstacles_tuple)
    try:
        if WINDOW.get_width() >= imgX > 0:
            WINDOW.blit(chosen_obstacle, (imgX, 323))
        else:
            imgX = w
    except pygame.error:
        quit()


r1, r2 = 5000, 7000
def timer(score):
    global r1, r2
    timer_running = True
    while timer_running:
        rand_time = random.randint(r1, r2)
        pygame.time.delay(rand_time)
        generate_obstacles()

        if r1 >= 500 and r2 >= 500:
            if score % 100 == 0:
                r1 -= 20
                r2 -= 20
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            break



game_intro(True)
run = True
my_sprite = Dino()
speed = 5
while run:
    bgX -= speed
    bgX2 -= speed
    imgX -= speed
    if bgX < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX = floor.get_width()
    if bgX2 < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX2 = floor.get_width()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            with open("highscore.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write(str(my_sprite.high_score))
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
            my_sprite.fall()

        if (keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]) and not my_sprite.is_jumping:
            my_sprite.jump()

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            my_sprite.bend()

    WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
    my_sprite.walk()

    if my_sprite.score >= 35:
        Thread(target=lambda: timer(my_sprite.score)).start()

    pygame.time.delay(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suspect that one issue with your code is that `pygame.display.update()` can be called concurrently by:

- the main program via the `draw` function ;
- and by the thread(s) you launch when the score is greater than 35 via the `draw_obstacles` function.

This may explain why some obstacles appear and disappear very quickly.  Maybe, just removing the `pygame.display.update()` in function `draw_obstacles` could fix that.

Another issue that may explain the lagging is related to your condition to launch the thread.  It seems to me that, as soon as the score exceeds 35, you will launch another thread at each iteration of the main loop, which means a *lot* of threads.  So, unless there is in your code some condition that can prevent that, you should add one.

**[EDIT]** After watching your full code I noticed a few issues.

First, as already mentionned, you should do `pygame.display.update()`
only *once* in your main loop.  Same for `WINDOW.fill` that you have
put have several places in your code.  That's what causes the effect
of objects appearing and disappearing very quickly.

Your program (and every pygame program) should have the following
structure.

```py
while run:
    process_events_and_change_objects_status()
    WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
    redraw_everything()
    pygame.display.update()
    wait()
```

And there should not be any other call to `WINDOW.fill` or
`pygame.display.update()` anywhere else.

Second, looking at the `fall` method:

```py
def fall(self):
    if self.is_falling:
        while self.y != 323:
            self.y += 20
            self.walk()
            WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
            self.is_falling = False
            self.is_jumping = False
            pygame.display.update()
```

Here you're trying to do two things at the same time: update the
object status and redraw everything with `self.walk`.  That's bad
because, for example, if there are currently obstacles on the screen,
they won't be drawned since `self.walk` does not care about obstacles.  Moreover this means that events cannot be processed while the dinosaur is falling.
So you have to change it to only update the object status with
something like that.

```py
def fall(self):
    if self.is_falling:
        self.y += 20
        if self.y != 323:
            self.is_falling = False
            self.is_jumping = False
```

Then redrawing will be managed by `self.walk` in the main loop.  Same
for `bend` and `jump`.

So I think that you need to modify your program structure in order to
clearly separate in your code the drawing part from the processing
part (processing events and updating the dinosaur status).  Otherwise
if you mix both you will face the kind of problems you are facing now
and your code will be impossible to maintain and evolve.

Comment: When I remove the `pygame.display.update()`, the obstacles don't show up at all. I started the thread before the main game loop and added the condition `if score >= 35` to the `timer` function. Doing this did not make the lagging stop. Can you try modifying my code? Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: you need to do the `pygame.display.update()` in the main loop.

Comment: @Kesslwovv, Ok I did that. But it does not solve my problem. The obstacles are still lagging and even show up less frequently than before.

Comment: @Roni Sorry to hear that.  Can you post the full code if its' not too big?

Comment: @qouify, It consists of over 200 lines, but if you still want me to post it, I will.

Comment: @Roni But why do you want to use thread here? I mean, can't you do everything in your main loop?  If you want to use thread then I would say that the thread should no draw anything but instead put the obstacles in a shared data structures and that the main program should look in that structures to draw the obstacles itself.  Because right now it's like having two people drawing at the same time on a board, each one erasing what the other is drawing.  And yes I would like to have a look at the full code, because it's hard to see the problem with the code snippet you posted.

Comment: @quoify, I want to use a thread due to the time delay. If I don’t use one, the other processes won’t be able to run simultaneously. I’ll post the full code in about 15 minutes.

Comment: @qouify, I added the full code

Comment: @Roni I looked at your code and edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @qouify, Thank you so much! Your answer really helped me. I did everything you suggested. In the fall method, I also added `self.y = 323`  to prevent the dinosaur from levitating. Your suggestions made the whole game smoother. Now I just need to finish making the obstacle system. I upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: @Roni Excellent! Glad I could help :)